# SNMP not available?

Tags: php, snmp

I have just upgraded PHP to :

PHP Version 5.4.4-14+deb7u10

on Linux debianWeb 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.54-2 x86_64
and there it fails:

2014-07-08 18:13:24: (mod_fastcgi.c.2676) FastCGI-stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'SNMP' not found in /var/www/get_snmp_data.php on line 6

```
    $session = new SNMP(SNMP::VERSION_1, "127.0.0.1", "public");
    $sysdescr = $session->get("sysDescr.0");
    echo "$sysdescr\n";
    $sysdescr = $session->get(array("sysDescr.0"));
    print_r($sysdescr);
```

(taken from somewhere else on Stackoverflow.)

Somebody has an idea?

Answer (score 1):

arg..

```
     apt-get install php5-snmp
```

that worked better.. (seems that stupid me forgot to do the php5- instead of just php-